# foundation 5 and angularjs; using `$(document).foundation();` many times

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I have an application that uses zurb's foundation 5 and angularjs 1.2.  Foundations 5 uses html5 `data-` attributes at many places.  For example in the [toolbar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html).

With angularjs, this do not behave very well together.  Basically, to make it work, I need to recall `$(document).foundation();` when html changes.

I am wandering if this heavy use of `$(document).foundation();` could cause problem in the long term?  Could I use something like `$("#foo").foundation();` when just a small portion of the html changes?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use directives to call third party plugin code

Answer (score 1):

This discussion is pretty helpful. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Htkzt7Fsaog